# Docker compose (v2) UnkownHostException

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I'm getting a "java.net.UnkownHostException: mysql: unknown error" when using Docker Compose and trying to link a spring boot web application container with a mysql container.

**docker-compose.yml** update #1

`version: '2'`

`services:`
  `web:`
    `depends_on:`
    `- db`
    `image: thomptr/rest-services-ui:latest`
    `ports:`
    `- "9000:9000"`
    `links:`
    `- "db:database"`
    `restart: always`
    `environment:`
      `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev`
      `envTarget: dev`

`db:`
    `image: mysql:5.7`
    `ports:`
    `- "3307:3306"`
    `volumes:`
    `- "/home/trevor/softwareDev/mySql/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"`
    `environment:`
      `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: legion03`
      `MYSQL_DATABASE: dev`
      `MYSQL_USER: dbuser`
      `MYSQL_PASSWORD: legion03`

**application-dev.properties** update #1

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
server.contextPath=/restservices
server.port: 9000

spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/dev

spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=legion03;
hibernate.level.logging=debug

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**logs from /dockercompose_web_1 container**

```
 2016-07-01 04:17:24.119 ERROR 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
```

UPDATE #2 The approach suggested by Nguyen Sy Thanh Son is correct. My solution uses the public wait-for-it.sh script.  See my solution here : https://github.com/thomptr/DockerDemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will occur when `web` container is up before `mysql` container being up.

To solve this issue, I think that you should add a script into your `entrypont.sh` of `web` image as below

```
host="db"
password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" #mysql root password

until mysql -h "$host" -uroot -p$password; do
  >&2 echo "MYSQL is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "MYSQL is up - executing command"

# start your app here
```

The script above will wait until mysql being up before running the application

And your Dockerfile of the application should contains:

```
# run app
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Link from container A to B will issue a dependency A depends on B. That means first will start db service, and after db is up it will start web. so this should be already covered.

Comment: No, It does not as our expectation. `Web` container connects `Mysql` when `db` container is not ready yet

Comment: @DimitrieMititelu I also am using the "depends on" statement which should ensure the "db" service is started before starting the "web" service

Comment: It seems others have discussed this issue and possible workarounds : https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/81

Comment: @Nguyen Sy Thanh Son your approach was correct.  My implementation used the wait-for-it.sh script and the solution can be found in my github repo : https://github.com/thomptr/DockerDemo

Answer (score 0):

i believe this error is due to the first container not knowing who is db.
links from container A to container B  will not modify /etc/hosts in both containers.

Another way to achieve this is with using aliases. you should find all info you need over here

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases

and modify the spring param:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<whatever alias you choose for db>:3306/dev`

Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: adding an alias on the link did not work and it also did not work when I later tried by using another network with an alias.

Comment: could you show us the docker-compose.yml that you are using ? with the alias ?

Comment: see my updates above to the docker-compose.yml and the application-dev.properties.  Please ignore the formatting mistakes in the .yml file as these were caused when trying to copy in code onto the page....  I'm also able to connect Mysql Workbench to the mysql container and see the schema loaded from the volume in the compose file.